# Wikitravel vs Wikivoyage - what's going to be the difference?

Tags: discussion

Many on this site have been cautious fans of [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/) in recent times, with it being run by Internet Brands.  With the [lawsuits between them and Wikimedia](http://gyrovague.com/2012/09/06/wikimedia-confirms-creation-of-travel-wiki-sues-internet-brands-to-end-legal-threats-against-volunteers/), and the impending fork to Wikivoyage, can someone familiar with the projects provide some insight as to what will happen to the respective sites?  It's something that we on stackexchange sites should follow with a keen interest, given the community-generated content, and especially so on travel.se, as these are the sites we'll choose to support and use...

Comment: Wikivoyage forked years ago. But only Italians and Germans were interested enough in it. The impending fork to Wikipedia is going to be a new fork as far as I know.

Comment: Isn't this better suited for meta?

Comment: [First rule of travel.se is that you do not talk about travel.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28679/the-rules-of-stack-overflow).

Comment: I am interested in this subject and I think many other travelers would also be interested.  Vote to keep.

Comment: It's not about travel, it's about sites about travel, therefore it's meta. I'm voting to move, which is a way of keeping (-:

Comment: I thought meta was for discussion about Travel.SE, which this thread is not?  Move it back, I say!

Comment: @hippietrail - it's a problem faced by travellers, and it's not about travel.se, so not meta.

Comment: @MarkMayo: As I've received in comments to some of my questions on other SE sites recently, "What exactly is the actual problem that you face?". I think this is pure discussion and best for the chat room, another great idea for an article on our blog, or on a travel forum like Lonely Planet Thorn Tree. Or here in Meta (-:

Comment: I think this *really* doesn't belong on Meta. The question is *not* about Travel.SE.

Answer (score 37):

Here's the short answer:

[image]

So basically Wikitravel's community and content are migrating to Wikimedia's new site, and Wikivoyage is only a temporary stepping stone until the servers etc are ready.

Wikitravel.org the site will keep running for some time, but with no contributors the content will either rot and fill up with spam, or get locked down and age into uselessness.

Comment: Did you actually do the graph solely to answer this question?

Comment: Excellent work - you're hired!

Comment: Which I wrote, and yes, this question was one of the reasons I went ahead and sketched that out.   Too many Wiki-somethings...

Comment: https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:Wikivoyage_and_Wikitravel

Comment: Four years later and Wikitravel is still alive and well :)

Comment: Ten years later and Wikitravel is still alive and well :)

Comment: @MEMark It's been slow going, but Wikivoyage now outranks WT on Alexa and is starting to generally have better content too.