# Is the Japanese edition of Wikitravel being forked to Wikivoyage?

Tags: discussion, wikivoyage

[Wikitravel vs Wikivoyage - what's going to be the difference?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/881/wikitravel-vs-wikivoyage-whats-going-to-be-the-difference) is a general question about what is happening with Wikitravel versus Wikivoyage.

The accepted answer claims that all "English, all other languages" are being forked from Wikitravel to Wikivoyage.

But Japan Wikivoyage not listed in the [splash page for Wikivoyage](http://www.wikivoyage.org/), and is just an [incubator](http://incubator.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wy/ja). What's happening?

Answer (score 4):

From the [discussion page on the various language versions](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikivoyage/New_language_versions#Japanese), it appears that the Japanese main editors weren't responsive to the requests of the Wikimedia group in regards to what they wanted to do with the project.  Best keeping an eye on that page for further updates, I'd say, unless someone else answers with more recent information...